# IF Statement not returning the value

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a jquery code that returns values from google spreadsheet.
What I want to do is have a function that determines if particular value contains a link, then use it in (`A` href) tag to make the link clickable.
 cant seem to get it to work.

```
function linknews() {
    var NLtext = "{{feed.feed.entry[0].gsx$newslink.$t}}";
    string(NLtext)
    var a = "no link"
    if (NLtext.indexOf("http://") >= 0) {
        a = "WE have a link";
    }
    document.write(a);
}
```

When I run it it comes up blank. I dont know what I am doing wrong it just comes up blank... Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you give us the complete JS code, please? This one is hardly readable and not correct JS. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example value for NLText? I assume youÄre replacing variables in it somehow.

Comment: IN my spreadsheet the value is either blank or has a link. {{feed.feed.entry[0].gsx$newslink.$t}} variable returns the value from that cell via jquery. I am not sure how it return if it blank, so i just converted it to string to be sure. The value IF it has something in it would be simple http://somesite.com with http: part in there

Comment: It works for me like that: `var NLtext = "http://www.google.de";
var a = "no link"
    if (NLtext.indexOf("http://") >-1) {
        a = "WE have a link";
    }
console.log(a)`

vs

`var NLtext = "I don't contain a link";
var a = "no link"
    if (NLtext.indexOf("http://") >-1) {
        a = "WE have a link";
    }
console.log(a)`

Comment: OK I am gonna give it a shot this way and see if it helps. Thanks